# Is there a pause function in Rstan

Tags: r, stan, rstan

Does anyone know if there is a way to pause in a for loop in Stan? Something like `Sys.sleep(duration)` but in Stan language. I would like to pause the for loop so I have time to read the statements I decided to print.

For now, I have two solutions that are not very elegant:

- Use a [break statement](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_27/reference-manual/break-and-continue-statements.html)
- `for (i in 1:1) {...}`, which cancel the loop

**In case of the solution would be platform-specific, I am on Linux or MacOS.**

Answer (score 1):

There is no pause function in (R)Stan, nor any compiled language that I know of.

In principle, one could run the model under a debugger like GDB or LLDB, set a breakpoint for the function that runs the loop, and step through the loop one statement at a time. I don't recommend that, but there are many relevant howtos on the internet, including one for [R packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Debugging-compiled-code).